# RegexPattern not working while matching words in C#

Tags: c#

I have to match a string to a list of values and find out which value is matched.

**List of Values**

```
USD
U S D
U/S/D
UNITED STATES DOLLARS
```

I used the below pattern.

```
(U|UNITED)(.)?(\s)?(S|STATES)(.)?(\s)?(D|DOLLARS)(.)?
```

I also used `Regex.Matches` to determine the value of the matched string.

It works perfectly fine for the below string except if the testdata has `UNITEDSTATESDOLLARS.`

The regex.matches returns only **UNITEDSTATESDO**.
Missing few letters from DOLLARS.
How do I fix the regex to retrieve all the matching words `UNITEDSTATESDOLLARS`

| Test data | Output value |
| --- | --- |
| testUSD | USD |
| testU.S.D | U.S.D |
| testU/S/D | U/S/D |
| testUNITEDSTATESDOLLARS | UNITEDSTATESDO** |

https://regex101.com/r/g7gh8a/1

Comment: There are two problems here. First, regex will try to match what's on the left first, so if you want `DOLLARS` to be matched when it appears instead of just the letter `D` and the letter after it, you should put `DOLLARS` first in the group. Second, unless you're using the case insensitive flag, `Dollars` will not match `DOLLARS`. Either make sure you're using the case insensitivity flag or change what it's looking for in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the pattern. The wordings in the pattern are case sensitive.

Comment: I think you mean `\.` not `.` because `.` matches _any character_ but `\.` matches a period.  Otherwise your expression will match something like `UPSIDE`.  Also, I think you want `(DOLLARS|D)`, not `(D|DOLLARS)` so it prefers to match the longer word first.

Comment: Changed the DOLLARS to match first and added \. at the end solved my issue."(U|UNITED)(.)?(\s)?(S|STATES)(.)?(\s)?(DOLLARS|D)(\.)?" Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a minimal change to your Regex:

```
var inputs = new []
{
    "testUSD",
    "testU S D",
    "testU/S/D",
    "testUNITED STATES DOLLARS",
};

var regex = new Regex(@"(U(NITED|)(.)?(\s)?S(TATES|)(.)?(\s)?D(OLLARS|)(.)?)");

Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        inputs.Select(i => regex.Match(i).Value)));
```

Basically I changed the order of what match you're accepting. So, instead of `(U|UNITED)` I went with `(UNITED|U)`. I changed that slightly to `U(NITED|)` to remove the redundancy - that may or may not have been an improvement.

Comment: Could also do `U(NITED)?`

Comment: @juharr - No, you can't. That would only match on `UNITED`.

Comment: Yes you can because the dollar sign means it will match U followed by an optional "NITED"

Comment: @juharr - Sorry, you're right. I thought the question-mark `?` was you asking a question, not part of the `Regex` you were suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex pattern :

```
^.*((USD)|(U[\.|\/|\s]*S[\.|\/|\s]*D)|(UNITED\s*STATES\s*DOLLARS)).*$
```

[image]

I tried the modified regex pattern above in a console application and it works fine ! See below :

Code:

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks . When I tried to retrieve the matched value (for eg testUSD should return USD , testU.S.D should return U.S.D) , the pattern you mentioned did not work.

Comment: @user16532412 : I alter the pattern a bit and could capture the expected values. See my edited post above.